# My images are loading too slow for the first time. I want to load it fast when user open it for the first time

Tags: wordpress

My images are loading too slow for the first time. I want to load it fast when user open it for the first time. I have added Wp fastest cache plugin. But after clear cache when I open the page, images are taking more time to load.

My page link: https://www.calienteconstruction.com/commercial-projects/

Comment: Is it relevant to image load?

Comment: There's a handy plugin in wordpress as LazyLoad research about that

Comment: @Diado: my bad! mistakenly posted that comment, it was for other post.

Answer (score 0):

Wp fastest cache plugin generates cache of the page by this reason images are loading fast after first time load.
For images, you can use Lazy Load plugin. it may help you.
If the still issue continues then optimize images for loading page fast.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Caching comes later, first, the images in that page need to be served in appropriate sizes (dimension/resolution).

Currently you are loading huge images (some 1600px wide, please [see](https://www.calienteconstruction.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Arizona-Bank.jpg)) and displaying them in a small size (340px approximately). What you need is show resized images -- which will be much smaller in size and significantly improve page load speed.

WordPress automatically creates different size images for you, and you can even add [custom](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/) images sizes and use those on the page.